# Add to value in Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a `Dictionary<Product, int> Inventory` which holds the inventory for the products that are in the shop.

How do I get the value that corresponds with the `Product` and add 1 to it?

It is also possible that the `Product` isn't in the dictionary.

Comment: What about an item that was not yet in stock? Does that exist in your dictionary with a value of zero, or is it missing from your dictionary? The current answer assumes it already exists.

Comment: @hvd valid point, it is possible that the product doesn't exist in the dictionary.

Comment: Be cautious with using the product as key in the dictionary. By default reference equality is used for classes. If one product is always represented by the same class instance (object), this is ok. Otherwise use a product id as key or override `Equals` and `GetHashcode` for the class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
myDictionary[myProduct] += stockIncrease;
```

It's pretty much exactly the syntax as you would use to update an item in an array.

If it helps, think of it less in terms of "I want to the stock to go up" and more in terms of "how do I get the value that I need, and what can I do with that value".

If it's not guaranteed whether or not your product exists in your dictionary to begin with, then just add on an if-check:

```
if (!inventory.ContainsKey(myProduct)) {
    inventory[myProduct] = 0;
}
inventory[myProduct] += stockIncrease;
```

Comment: or `if (!inventory.ContainsKey(myProduct)) {
    inventory[myProduct] = 1;
} else {
    inventory[myProduct] += stock_increase;
}` in order to avoid accessing the dictionary 3 times.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes That still accesses the dictionary three times. First in the call to `ContainsKey`, then in the property getter for `inventory[myProduct]`, and finally in the property setter for `inventory[myProduct]`.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes - I figured that HashMaps are O(1), I might as well pick the way that looks cleanest to me and not worry about efficiency, but yeah, your way should work just as well (though you probably want to initially set the inventory size to `stockIncrease` to stay consistent)

Comment: I'm not sure how this will be implemented by the compiler; however, it will be one time less, I guess.

Comment: @Michael0x2a: Yes of course `stockIncrease`, not `1`!

Answer (score 2):

To deal with items that don't yet exist in your dictionary, my personally preferred way is to use `TryGetValue`:

```
int stock;
inventory.TryGetValue(product, out stock);
inventory[product] = stock + 1;
```

This works because `TryGetValue` sets `stock` to `default(int)`, which is `0`, if the product does not yet exist. `0` is exactly the value you want.

If you prefer to treat the `stock` value as unassigned after `TryGetValue` returns `false` (for readability), then you can still use this same general approach:

```
int stock;
if (!inventory.TryGetValue(product, out stock))
  stock = 0;
inventory[product] = stock + 1;
```